# What are values mapped to?

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I don't understand how Ruby hashes work.

I expect these:

```
a = 'a'
{a => 1}[a] # => 1
{a: 1}[:a] # => 1
{2 => 1}[2] # => 1
```

How does this work?

```
{'a' => 1}['a'] # => 1
```

The first string `'a'` is not the same object as the second string `'a'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
some_hash[k] = v
```

Basically, when you do this, what is stored is **not** a direct association `k => v`. Instead of that, `k` is asked for a [hash code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which is then used to map to `v`.

Equal values yield equal hash codes. That's why your last example works the way it does.

A couple of examples:

```
1.9.3p0 :001 > s = 'string'
 => "string" 
1.9.3p0 :002 > 'string'.hash 
 => -895223107629439507 
1.9.3p0 :003 > 'string'.hash == s.hash
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :004 > 2.hash
 => 2271355725836199018 
1.9.3p0 :005 > nil.hash
 => 2199521878082658865
```

Comment: There is still a comparison happening, just not with equal?. The hash is just used to place the values into buckets, comparisons of keys are needed to deal with collisions

Comment: -1. Hashing has nothing to do with this; a BST-based container might exhibit the exact same behavior.

Comment: I would delete my answer in favor of Frederick's, but it is accepted.

Comment: The hash code is a red herring. It's simply a performance optimization. The important factor is that `Hash` uses `eql?`, not `equal?` for determining equality.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby doesn't use object equality  (`equal?`) for comparing hash keys. It wouldn't be very useful if it did after all.

Instead it uses `eql?`, which for strings is the same as `==`

Answer (score 3):

As a footnote to other answers, you can let a hash behave like you expected:

```
h = {'a'=> 1}
p h['a'] #=> 1
h.compare_by_identity
p h['a'] #=> nil ; not the same object
```